# Webfonts for icons in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, font-face

I'm using a web font for icons instead of image files.  I was given the original font by a designer, and then I made the full set through [Font Squirrel's @font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).  I opened up the test `*.html` file that they deliver along with the exported fonts, and it worked consistently in every browser I looked at (including IE7).

I installed the font on my server, and again it worked consistently in every browser I tested (including IE9) **except IE7**.  The strange thing is that it works about half the time in IE7.  So if I just repeatedly refresh the page, then it will randomly work about half the page loads, and not work the other half.

I have cleared the cache several times through the 'Developer Tools' window.

Here is the CSS I'm using to include the font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'iconRegular';
    src: url('/static/fonts/icon-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/static/fonts/icon-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/static/fonts/icon-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/static/fonts/icon-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/static/fonts/icon-webfont.svg#iconRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

.icon,
.ui-widget-content .icon {
    font-family: 'iconRegular';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
}
```

I am using this in a massive application (~20 `*.js` files loaded through `require.js`); is it possible that this is related to the size of my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be a bug in IE7/8 `@font-face` handling that showed up in heavyweight web applications (my app had ~25 stylesheets and ~50 Javascript script tags).  I fixed it by browser sniffing for IE7/8 (for shame!), waiting 500 ms after page load, then adding a second `<link>` tag to the stylesheet containing the font declaration.